# Calculate Shortest Route On Grid

Tags: java

I have two points. One being the position of the player and another position of the enemy.

I would like to find out how to calculate the shortest distance for the player to get to the enemy. The player can't move diagonally, only up, down, left, and right.

This is a grid. so top left corner is 0,0 etc. etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: If there are obstacles I would use a [Breadth First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), [Dijkstra's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) or [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm). If there are no obstacles I would use the [Manhatten Distance](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance). But maybe its better to Google a bit and try out to solve it on your own and come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Your question should be more specific. Have you put any effort in finding solution? Have you implemented anything? Read anything about pathfinding / maybe graphs / algorithms that might be used to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the [Dijkstra algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) on a graph where each node represents a cell of your grid, and each edge has a cost of one (which would allow you to use a breath first search, but for more general use, having the full Dijkstra algorithm can help you).

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know what the shortest path is since we don't know exactly what you're talking about. If it is just a standard grid with nothing in between the player and the enemy, then the shortest path is trivial. Any path that goes down and over the proper units without going back is the shortest path. Going down the full units and then to the side the full units is as short as going down and then to the side and then down and then to the side unit the coordinates line up.

If you have obstacles, though, then the Dijkstra algorithm will help, as Jonathan mentioned. You simply don't include the parts of the grid that you can't access. Your algorithm will then be forced to find a path around the obstacles since it can't go through the nodes.